# Redirect one page only once in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Redirect one page onlye one time, not 2nd time, then again on 3rd time but not 4th time. I am not sure this kind of stuff is possible in htaccess or not, but I really need to get this done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Redirect one Page url to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933812/how-to-redirect-one-page-url-to-another)