# How to Redirect one Page url to another

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, magento

I want to redirect one page to another page which is something like below..

http://dev.****.in:82/abc/wp redirect to http://dev.****.in:82/abc/blog

I have tried the below code on .htaccess but no luck.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.xxx\.in\/:\/82\/abc$

RewriteRule ^wp$ "http\:\/\/dev\.xxx\.in\/:\/82\/abc\/blog" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: do you want to redirect only 1 page?

Comment: @Helping Hands : yes I want to redirect only one page.

Comment: Kindly try `Redirect 301 /http://dev.****.in:82/abc/wp  http://dev.****.in:82/abc/blog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to redirect this url is RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch ^/abc/wp/?$ /abc/blog
```